# programmable search engine json Api

Tags: angular, search-engine

I am currently developing a program that uses the JSON Api of Google's programmable search engine. Everything works fine, I also get the desired results, unfortunately the first 10. I've no idea, how i can use the nextPage option. Has someone a code example for unsing the nextPage Option?

Comment: please add some code snippet on what have you tried so far, and what are you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Sorry about my late answers, I was very busy with my own project.

In the JSON answer, you get from the server, there are some sections in the header. One of these sections called 'queries'. in queries you find a subsection 'nextPage' and the is the parameter 'startIndex'.

On your query url You should add one parameter "&start=(startindex).

At the moment I change my Code, I will post it in the next couple of days.